# Symmetric Endomorphism: Prove that kernel $\perp$ image

Tags: linear-algebra

### Exercise

Let $(V, < , >)$ be an euclidian vector space and B an orthonormal basis regarding $< , >$. Let $p$ be an endomorphism of $V$, so that $M_B^B(p)$ (the transformation matrix) is symmetric.

Show that $ker(p) \perp im(p)$.

### My attempt

M is symmetric

$\Rightarrow$ p is self-adjoint.

$\Rightarrow$ {v $\in$ V | p(v) = 0} = {0}

The image of p is im(p) = span(B)

$\Rightarrow ker(p) \perp im(p)$.

### Question

Is this a sufficient proof? If not, how can I improve it?

Comment: The kernel of $p$ need not be zero.

Comment: Oh ok, but how can I prove it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove that if we denote with $f^{*}$ the adjoint endomorphism of $f$, that $Ker(f^{*}) = Im(f)^{\perp}$ :

Infact if $x \in Ker(f^{*}), \forall y \in V \langle f(y),x \rangle = \langle y,f^{*}(x) \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow x \in Im(f)^{\perp}$.

Conversely if $x \in Im(f)^{\perp}, \forall y \in V, \langle y,f^{*}(x) \rangle = \langle f(y),x \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow f^{*}(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x \in Ker(f^{*})$.

It holds that $Im(f^{*}) = Ker(f)^{\perp}$, since from the previous you can take $f^{*}$ in the place of $f$.

If $f$ is self adjoint, $f = f^{*}$, the proof follows directly.